mongodb multiple join conditions on lookup
Trying to build lookup query between two collections following this pattern:
MongoDB Lookup Reference Multiple Join Conditions
But I'm not joining on my lookup table and getting those fields available.
Data:
  api: [
    {
      "client": "AA",
      "msgNm": "mesg1",
      "volume": 76409,
      "month": "2024-08"
    },
    {
      "client": "AA",
      "msgNm": "mesg2",
      "volume": 33047,
      "month": "2024-08"
}
...
  cpu: [
    {
      "lob": "AA",
      "msgNm": "mesg1",
      "mips": 7609,
      "month": "2024-08"
    },
    {
      "lob": "AA",
      "msgNm": "mesg2",
      "mips": 3347,
      "month": "2024-08"
    },

Current Query:
db.api.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "cpu",
      let: {
        cpuClient: "$lob",
        cpuMsg: "$msgName",
        cpuMonth: "$yrMon",
        cpuMips: "$mips"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [ "$month", "2024-08" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$$cpuMonth", "2024-08" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$client", "$$cpuClient" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$msgNm", "$$cpuMsg" ] }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "joined"
    }
  }
])

Fuller Example at the MongoDB Playground

There are couple typos. In let, the variables should be referring to the field in the source collections (i.e. api in your case). So, 1.  $lob should be $cpuClient 2. $yrMon should be $month

In $match stage, you are operating on target collection(i.e. cpu) 3. $client should be $lob

See full example here

thanks ray. I see now the reason for the let stanza, to allow comparisons from src coll to lookup'ed collection fields.
